# Java Web App upload and load images

Tags: java, web-applications

So, i am developing simple web application using Spring Framework.

The application users can upload images.

What is best practices for storing/loading images?

I found solution on some forum, where someone suggested to store files to user.dir directory.

Ok, i also do that.

When user upload image i store the image to user.dir directory.

Now, i have a question: how to load image from user.dir directory to page?

```
 <img src="path/to/dir/where/images/stored"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is indeed to store such data outside the webapp's tree to avoid issues on redeployment.  Where exactly they get stored is more a matter of convention, user.dir can indeed be a reasonable choice.

You can't serve these files directly though, commonly it's done by creating a servlet mapped to eg `images/*` that parse the request URL (eg `<img src="approot/images/apic.jpg"/>`) and based on that url if fetches and serves `path/to/dir/where/images/stored/apic.jpg`. As an added bonus that servlet gives you full control over what gets downloaded, when and by who, maybe you will need this kind of control later on in the application lifecycle.

You can use [getPathInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) to retrieve the part of the URL following the servlet name, set the correct MIME type for the output, and streamcopy the requested file to the servlet's output.

A publicly available, well explained example of such a servlet can be found on [BalusC's blog](http://balusc.blogspot.be/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Answer (score 0):

We recently had a similar situation in one of our project so we decided to store all the user profile pics in a folder in application dir. Then in our servlet implementation we retrieved the path to folder so that we can have a platform independent implementation there after whenever we had to store a img we stored the dynamically generated img name along with other profile details in db thus storage and retrieval are just a matter of db lookups and in future if we need to change the dir of img all we need to do is update the value of path variable.

Hope it helps

all the best. ..!!!